# Consulta SQL: último valor del sector

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla que tiene miles de valores...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deseo traerme el último turno por caja (son 6 cajas). O sea, el resultado tendría que ser una tabla de solo 6 registros:

Para el ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es la mejor forma de hacerlo?

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
select * 
from tabla1 
order by fecha desc
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Qué manejador de base de datos usas? ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio.
Intento esto:

select * from tabla1 order by fecha desc, caja

Pero esto, obviamente, me ordena todas las fechas primero y luego las cajas... No es lo que estoy buscando.

Comment: A ver.. SQL Server Management Studio es una ide.. estas trabajando con SQL server... y luego, esto es un simplre group by... lee sobre eso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select CONCAT(caja, ' - ', turno) as "Caja - Turno", max(fecha) as Fecha
from tabla
group by CONCAT(caja, ' - ', turno);
```

Lo que debes hacer es uso de la **cláusula group by** junto a una **función de agregación** en la **cláusula select**, en este caso la **funcion de agregación** que se utiliza es max, de este modo se retorna la fecha mas reciente.

Cuando se hace uso de la **cláusula group by** debe tenerse en cuenta una regla de **SQL** que dice que el campo que no aparezca en la **cláusula group by** debe aparecer en el **select** con una **función de agregación**, por eso para no complicar la consulta concateno los **campos Caja y Turno**, para tratarlos como uno solo, y agrupo por la concatenación de esos campos, de no hacerlo así puedes verte tentado a hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
select caja, turno, max(fecha) as Fecha
from tabla
group by caja
```

La cual es incorrecta ya que el **campo turno** no aparece en la **cláusula group by** y tampoco aparece con una **función de agregación** en la **cláusula select**, lo cual viola la regla de **SQL** antes descrita.

Hacerlo de esta forma:

```
select caja, turno, max(fecha) as Fecha
from tabla
group by caja, turno
```

También es incorrecto ya que a ti lo que te hace falta es agrupar solamente por el **campo Caja**, y de hacerlo así la consulta no estará mal(no te dará error) pero obtendrás un resultado incorrecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias Japv!! De todas maneras eso no me va a funcionar porque no deseo ver todos los pares Caja-turno, sinó solo ver los turnos correspondientes a la max(fecha). 
Lo solucioné con una tabla temporal donde guardo los campos caja y fecha haciendo un group by por fecha y luego joineo esta tabla con un inner join a la anterior para traerme el campo "turno".

Muchas gracias de nuevo Japv!

Comment: @Raulus me parece q no entendiste mi respuesta, y si funciona, te recomiendo q la vuelvas a leer y la analices bien :)